# Show that all solutions are of the form $(t,t^2,t^3)$

Tags: real-analysis, systems-of-equations, submanifold

I want to show that there exists a global map of a submanifold described as the solution of the equations below. So I found one map, but I need to know if it contains all possible solutions.

How does one show that all real solutions of the system of equations:

$x^2+xy-y-z = 0$

$2x^2+3xy-2y-3z = 0$

are of the form: $(t,t^2,t^3)$ ?

Comment: Solve one equation or the other for $z$ and substitute, then the result becomes a linear equation in $y$ with the free parameter $x$. The given solution parametrizes everything by $x$ itself.

Comment: Thank you!.....